# How can I get javascript value in php when using phantomjs in javascript

Tags: php, phantomjs

I want to write some php code which can be able to get the value of javascript(included phantomjs code and phantomjs installed), how should i do if i want to get the value of javascript to php?

***javascript***

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://www.lazada.com.my/products/xiaomi-original-mi-backpack-simple-urban-life-style-bag-dark-grey-i116600345-s121584557.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.4.41755f1dNNJa0E&search=1',function(){ 
    var name = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.getElementsByClassName("pdp-mod-product-badge-title") 
        [0].value;
    });
    document.write(name);
});
phantom.exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Running this snippet from a web-browser won't work, we need to load this script using PhantomJS. So we save this snippet in a file test.js, can be anything you want to name it. Then from the command line, run.

phantomjs test.js

Hope you already install phantomjs.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/what-is-phantomjs-and-how-is-it-used

try this:

```
    page.open('https://www.lazada.com.my/products/xiaomi-original-mi- 
        backpack-simple-urban-life-style-bag-dark-grey-i116600345- 
        s121584557.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlist.list.4.41755f1dNNJa0E&search=1', 
        function(){ 
        var name = page.evaluate(function(){
            return document.getElementsByClassName("pdp-mod-product-badge-title") 
            [0].value;
        });

        return name;
        phantom.exit();
    });
```

Comment: so that's mean javascript with phantomjs cant run on html? so if i want to get the value from javascript with phantomjs to php what should i do?